# How to make the Table of Contents, List of Figures, List of Tables to appear in Uppercase?

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, capitalization

The following images depict my Lyx doc which gives the first output when converted to PDF. I am looking to capitalize them. I am using Koma documentclass

[image: What is the procedure to follow to make these headings into Uppercase. I tried right clicking them to see if they have any options. But, there seems to be nothing. It gives out No action Defined.]

[image: Currently it is looking like this:]

This is the current Latex Preamble:

```
\date{}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

%this command set the paragraph indentation if you want to modify change the value 1.5cm to your preference
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

%This command will change the default Bibliography to References
\AtBeginDocument{
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
    \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
}

%The following comands center the heading of chapters and chapter entries, the default is on the left
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\centering}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\centering\fontsize{20.66}{20.66}\selectfont\color{black}}

% The following commands set the page numbers on the top right except in the beginning of chapters using fancyhdr package (page layout>heading style->fancy)
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% The following commands set the vertical space before and after every chapter entry
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{2cm}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{2.5cm}}

% The following commands set the TOC, LOT, LOF and LOA: this employs tocloft package
\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{2.5cm}

\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill \hfill 
%\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill \hfill \hfill
\\[3\baselineskip]{Figure No \hfill Title \hfill Page \linebreak} \vskip-50pt}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{2.5cm}

\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill \hfill
%\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill \hfill\hfill
\\[3\baselineskip]{Table No \hfill Title \hfill Page \linebreak }
\vskip-50pt}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{2.5cm}

\newlistof{appendices}{loa}{List of Appendices}
\renewcommand{\cftloatitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloatitle}{\hfill \hfill
%\renewcommand{\cftafterloatitle}{\hfill \hfill\hfill 
\\[3\baselineskip]{Appendix \hfill Title \hfill Page  \linebreak} 
\vskip-60pt}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforeloatitleskip}{2.5cm}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{1.9cm}{1.2cm}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\qquad\quad\,\,}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\qquad\quad\,\,\,\, }
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{\quad\,\, }
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnumb}{\qquad\qquad\,}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnumb}{\quad}

\usepackage{minitoc}

% Redefining automatic label of Figure, Table and Eq.
\usepackage{prettyref}
\newrefformat{tab}{Table\,\ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{fig}{Figure\,\ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{eq}{Eq.\,\textup{(\ref{#1})}}

%To remove extra vertical space in List of Symbols [added in V-05]
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

% from koma-script scrbook.cls, then modified [added in V-05] to shift addchap in TOC to the right: \qquad\qquad\,\,
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\addchap{
   \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage
   \fi
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   \global\@topnum\z@
   \@afterindentfalse
   \secdef\@addchap\@saddchap}
   \def\@addchap[#1]#2{
           \typeout{#2}
           \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\qquad\qquad\,\, #1}
                    \if@twoside\@mkboth{#1}{}\else\@mkboth{}{#1}
                    \fi
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
                    \if@twocolumn
                         \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#2}]
                         \else
                         \@makeschapterhead{#2}
                         \@afterheading
                    \fi
                    }
    \def\@saddchap#1{\@mkboth{}{}
            \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]
                      \else
                      \@makeschapterhead{#1}
                      \@afterheading
             \fi
}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{0}{1.5em}{4.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{0}{1.5em}{4.3em}}
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}
\makeatother
```

[image: Can you please tell me how to make it like:]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know much about ERTs. But in latex, you can add these to your preamble

```
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase{Table of Contents}}
\renewcommand*{\listoflotname}{\MakeUppercase{List of Tables}}
\renewcommand*{\listoflofname}{\MakeUppercase{List of Figures}}
```

Or do it koma way by adding `\setkomafont{chapter}{\MakeUppercase}` before the lists and `\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalfont}` after.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext,xcolor}
%\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase{Table of Contents}}
%\renewcommand*{\listoflotname}{\MakeUppercase{List of Tables}}
%\renewcommand*{\listoflofname}{\MakeUppercase{List of Figures}}
\newcommand*{\mychap}{\centering\fontsize{20.66}{20.66}\selectfont\color{black}}
\begin{document}
  \setkomafont{chapter}{\mychap\MakeUppercase}
  \tableofcontents
  \listoftables
  \listoffigures
  \addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalfont}
  \begin{table}
  \caption{Some table}
  \end{table}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{a figure}
  \end{figure}
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have \addtokomafont{chapter}{\centering\fontsize{20.66}{20.66}\selectfont\color{black}}

So, if I add \addtokomafont{chapter}{\MakeUppercase\centering\fontsize{20.66}{20.66}\selectfont\color{black}} --
It is throwing out errors. Can you please suggest the correct implementation?
Thanks

Comment: @hank: Try instead with `\addtokomafont{chapter}{\centering\fontsize{20.66}{20.66}\selectfont\MakeUppercase}`.

Comment: @Werner:I am getting -
 \chapter{INTRODUCTION\label{cha:Introduction}}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
and
Missing control sequence as errors when I follow your suggestion.

Comment: @HarishKumar - even the \renewcommand does not make any difference.

Comment: @hank I have edited the answer. Pl. give feedback.

Comment: @HarishKumar - I have tried the suggestions related to komafont. But, there seems to no change. Would you want me to provide any other related material to better diagnose the problem?

Comment: Can you export your file as latex code and post it in the question?

Comment: @HarishKumar - Can I send it to you directly?

Comment: Maybe add letterspacing?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen - Where should the letterspacing be added?

Comment: @hank In the titles as they are all upper case letters. It makes it easier to read them. See e.g. `microtye` package for more information about letterspacing (a.k.a. tracking) and how to enable it.